# Draw real graph (graphviz?)

Tags: graph, graphviz

I´m working with different graph algorithms, and for testing, and see the results, i need to visualize the graph.

I´m trying to use graphviz for visualization, but i dont want to use any Layout Engine, just use the real coordinates of the points.

For example: some TSPLIB instances have coordinates like: 1.54400e+04 8.88800e+03

Is this posible? should i use another tool?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the nodes like

```
nodename [pos="2,4!"];
```

to position them at `(x=2|y=4)` (the unit is inches).

Comment: Thanks ! But the coordinates values are very big as i said: 1.54400e+04 8.88800e+03 this draw a gigant graph?

Comment: I am sure you can find a way to map that large range of numbers to a smaller number for your application. Try square roots, logarithms, multiplying with 0.001, or sorting the numbers into a list and using the index into the list instead of the number. Be creative. :)

Comment: I will try, i only have the hope that graphviz scale the graph automatically :(

Answer (score -1):

Try GoogleCharts
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Comment: Graphviz is much better then Google Charts. Also for totally a different purpose.